# Expressjs / Nodejs route works with POST, but not with PUT

Tags: express, post, put

I'm changing nothing but changing the route method from "Post" to "Put", and for some reason that breaks it.

The POST route works fine:

In route in App.js with POST:

```
 app.post('/editlisting/update',listing.update);
```

the editListing.jade file that submits to it:

```
extends layout

block content
  div(class="container")
      ul(class="userlist")
      each listing, i in listings
        li
          h1 #{listing.name}
          form(method='post', action='update' class='regform')
            label Name:
            input(type='text', name='name', value='#{listing.name}')
            br
            label Number of Guests:
            input(type='text', name='noGuests', value='#{listing.noGuests}')
            input(type='hidden', name='id', value='#{listing._id}')
            label Price:
            input(type='text', name='price', value='#{listing.price}')
            input(type='submit', value='Update')
            a(href='/') Home
```

The Update method in listing.js (I don't change this at all):

```
      exports.update = function(req,res){
  var conditions = {_id:req.body.id}
  , update = {
       name: req.body.name,
       noGuests: req.body.noGuests,
       price: req.body.price
     }
  , options = { multi: false };

Listing.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

  function callback (err, numAffected) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    res.redirect('/');
  };

 }
```

Then when I try to change it to PUT....

app.js:

```
app.put('/editlisting/update',listing.update);
```

editListing.Jade:

extends layout

```
block content
  div(class="container")
      ul(class="userlist")
      each listing, i in listings
        li
          h1 #{listing.name}
          form(method='put', action='update' class='regform')
            label Name:
            input(type='text', name='name', value='#{listing.name}')
            br
            label Number of Guests:
            input(type='text', name='noGuests', value='#{listing.noGuests}')
            input(type='hidden', name='id', value='#{listing._id}')
            label Price:
            input(type='text', name='price', value='#{listing.price}')
            input(type='submit', value='Update')
            a(href='/') Home
```

This causes my browser to display this error when I press the "Update" button:

4| div(class="container") 5| ul(class="userlist") > 6| each listing, i in listings 7| li 8| h1 #{listing.name} 9| form(method='put', action='update' class='regform') Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

And it points to the line in my editListing.jade file:

```
   each listing, i in listings
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you still have req.body available when you change the method to PUT? Console.log(req.body) in your update function to check. Also check if there are any entries made in your database after you update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way you can do is method overriding

run npm install method-override

include it in your application after body-parser
something like this

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override')
    app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Then modify your html

```
 block content
  div(class="container")
      ul(class="userlist")
      each listing, i in listings
        li
          h1 #{listing.name}
          form(method='POST', action='/editlisting/update?_method=PUT' class='regform')
            label Name:
            input(type='text', name='name', value='#{listing.name}')
            br
            label Number of Guests:
            input(type='text', name='noGuests', value='#{listing.noGuests}')
            input(type='hidden', name='id', value='#{listing._id}')
            label Price:
            input(type='text', name='price', value='#{listing.price}')
            input(type='submit', value='Update')
            a(href='/') Home
```

then you'll be able to use

```
app.put('/editlisting/update',listing.update);
```